# Which method will this inherited class call (virtual function)? c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Say I have a base class

```
class Base
{

public:
void A() {do stuff};
void B() {A(); do stuff};
};
```

and a derived class

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
void A() {do things}
};

Derived derived1;
derived1.B();
```

will B call A of the base class or the A of the derived class?

I suspect B will call the A of the base class, and that in order for it to use the new redefined A, I have to make it virtual:

```
class Base
{

public:
virtual void A() {do stuff};
void B() {A(); do stuff};
};
```

Is that correct? Is that what virtual functions are used for?

Comment: Couldn't you just test it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct on both counts...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Base
{
public:
virtual void A() {do stuff};
void B() { do stuff};
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
void A() {do things}
void B() {do things}
};
```

and

```
Derived d;
Base *p = &d;
p->A();
p->B();
```

function B will not be overrided